# Crontab not running my shell script

Tags: command-line, scripts, cron

For some reason my crontab is not running my shell script, the shell sends me an email when disk space is full.
This is my script

```
#!/bin/bash
CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
THRESHOLD=10
if [ "$CURRENT" -gt "$THRESHOLD" ]; then
  echo "Percent used: $USE" | mail -s "The disk space is full!" myemail@hotmail.com
fi
```

This is the command in crontab for my user called magento_home and root.

```
* * * * */home/magento_admin/AlertDisk.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do know that a user `crontab` file, and `root`'s `crontab` have different formats, right? The latter has a `userid` field.

The environment that a `cron` jobs runs in is not the same as your GUI environment. Execute `(echo "=== set ===";set;echo "===env ==="; env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias)` in each environment to see.

Also, `* * * * */home/magento_admin/AlertDisk.sh` should be
.........`* * * * * /home/magento_admin/AlertDisk.sh`

Comment: Thank you very much, I just changed for * * * * *(space)/home/magento_admin/AlertDisk.sh and it totally worked.